# Avoid double binding on DOM events (with onclick() for example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a few DOM Components on which I bind events like `click`,`hover`, etc....
Because I use `JSF` with `AJAX`, sometimes these components get re-rendered and then I have to rebind the DOM events to them.

To achieve the automatic re-binding of newly rendered components I register with `JSF` event to rebind in this manner:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function (data) {
    if (data.status === "success") {
        $("#someid").click(function() {...});
    }
});
```

Problem with this solution is that when the components are not re-rendered but an `AJAX` event occurs, the binding is doubled and tripled and so on.

A solution that pop up to my head is to have a flag for each DOM component that is set to true when the component was bound to an event.
It will work but is a little cumbersome.

*I'm wondering* if there is a better solution that I don't know of (or can't think of), like some kind of `jQuery` feature that allows the programmer to avoid more than one binding per event per DOM component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is exactly what `jQuery.live()` is for.

*EDIT*: As noted in the comments, as of jQuery 1.7, the correct method to use is [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: if you use jQuery >= 1.7 you want  to use .one()

Comment: @pna - `one()` does an automatic `unbind()` after the first event is triggered.  That has nothing to do with what the OP is asking about.  The OP needs `.live()` or `.on()` so newly added elements have one and only one event binding without having to manually bind them.